# Cannot use "useLocation" outside of react-router <RouterProvider> Uncaught Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm trying to use the `useLocation` hook in my component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { useNProgress } from '@tanem/react-nprogress';
import type { PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

import type { AppState } from '@/store/app';
import { uiActions } from '@/store/reducers/ui';

import EDProgressBarView from './EDProgressBar.view';

interface IPropsFromState {
    readonly isProgressBarVisible: boolean;
}

interface IPropsFromDispatch {
    readonly closeProgressBar: () => PayloadAction;
}

interface IProps extends IPropsFromState, IPropsFromDispatch {}

const EDProgressBar: React.FC<IProps> = (props: React.PropsWithChildren<IProps>) => {
    const { animationDuration, isFinished, progress } = useNProgress({
        isAnimating: props.isProgressBarVisible,
        incrementDuration: 200,
    });

    const location = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
        props.closeProgressBar();
    }, [location]);

    return (
        <EDProgressBarView
            animationDuration={animationDuration}
            isFinished={isFinished}
            progress={progress}
        />
    );
};

EDProgressBar.displayName = 'EDProgressBar';
EDProgressBar.defaultProps = {};

const mapStateToProps = (state: AppState) => {
    return {
        isProgressBarVisible: state.ui.isProgressBarVisible,
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
    closeProgressBar: uiActions.closeProgressBar,
})(React.memo(EDProgressBar));
```

And I place this component here:

```
import React, { Suspense, useMemo } from 'react';
import { RouterProvider, createBrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import EDNotification from '@/ui/EDNotification';
import EDProgressBar from '@/ui/EDProgressBar';

import RouterBuilder from './App.router';

interface IProps {
    readonly isAuthenticated: boolean | null;
}

const AppView: React.FC<IProps> = (props: React.PropsWithChildren<IProps>) => {
    const routes = useMemo(() => {
        return RouterBuilder(props.isAuthenticated);
    }, [props.isAuthenticated]);

    return (
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
            <RouterProvider router={createBrowserRouter(routes)} fallbackElement={null} />

            <div id="backdrop-root" />
            <div id="overlay-root" />

            <EDNotification />
            <EDProgressBar />
        </Suspense>
    );
};

AppView.displayName = 'AppView';
AppView.defaultProps = {};

export default React.memo(AppView);
```

So then I get an error:

```
Uncaught Error: useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.
```

But I don't understand how can I do such thing if `RouterProvider` component does not accept any children of something like a component to inject it.
I need this `EDProgressBar` component to exist in the application regardless of the active route. I need it to exist in every page.

How can I do so?

This is my RouterBuild:

```
import React from 'react';
import { type RouteObject } from 'react-router-dom';


const CliAuth = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/CliAuth'));
const CliAuthenticated = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/CliAuthenticated'));
const NotFound = React.lazy(() => import('./pages/NotFound'));


const RouterBuilder = (isAuthenticated: boolean | null) => {

    const generalRoutes: RouteObject[] = [
        {
            path: 'cli-auth',
            element: <CliAuth />,
        },
        {
            path: 'cli-authenticated',
            element: <CliAuthenticated />,
        },
        {
            path: 'not-found',
            element: <NotFound />,
        },
        {
            path: '*',
            element: isAuthenticated === null ? null : <NotFound />,
        },
    ];

    return [...(isAuthenticated ? authorizedRoutes : unAuthorizedRoutes), ...generalRoutes];
};

export default RouterBuilder;
```

Note that I removed some routes because they are irrelevant here, but the important thing is that I use the `loader` key in some, so I need this builder.

Comment: The problem is that the provider uses react's context feature: https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context#step-3-provide-the-context, so you have to make your notifications, and progress bar part of the route that actually uses them, or use the BrowerRouter directly instead of through RouterProvider

Comment: The `useLocation` and other RRD hooks can't be used outside any routing context provided by a router. Can you share the `RouterBuilder` code?

Comment: @DrewReese I added the block code for `RouterBuilder` in the end of the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useLocation` and other RRD hooks can't be used outside any routing context provided by a router. I suggest creating a layout route that renders the `EDNotification` and `EDProgressBar` components and the backdrop and overlay divs. This layout route will be included in the routes returned by `RouterBuilder`. This allows the components accessing the routing context to have the router higher than them in the ReactTree.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const AppLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Outlet />
    <div id="backdrop-root" />
    <div id="overlay-root" />

    <EDNotification />
    <EDProgressBar />
  </>
);

const RouterBuilder = (isAuthenticated: boolean | null) => {
  const generalRoutes: RouteObject[] = [
    {
      path: 'cli-auth',
      element: <CliAuth />,
    },
    {
      path: 'cli-authenticated',
      element: <CliAuthenticated />,
    },
    {
      path: 'not-found',
      element: <NotFound />,
    },
    {
      path: '*',
      element: isAuthenticated === null ? null : <NotFound />,
    },
  ];

  const routes = [
    {
      element: <AppLayout />
      children: [
        ...(isAuthenticated ? authorizedRoutes : unAuthorizedRoutes),
        ...generalRoutes
      ],
    }
  ];

  return routes;
};
```

```
const AppView: React.FC<IProps> = (props: React.PropsWithChildren<IProps>) => {
  const routes = useMemo(() => {
    return RouterBuilder(props.isAuthenticated);
  }, [props.isAuthenticated]);

  return (
    <Suspense fallback={null}>
      <RouterProvider
        router={createBrowserRouter(routes)}
        fallbackElement={null}
      />
    </Suspense>
  );
};
```